# What is the difference between using constructor vs getInitialState in React / React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, constructor

I've seen both used interchangeably.

What are the main use cases for both?    Are there advantages / disadvantages?    Is one a better practice?

Answer (score 990, accepted):

The two approaches are not interchangeable. You should initialize state in the constructor when using ES6 classes, and define the `getInitialState` method when using `React.createClass`.

[See the official React doc on the subject of ES6 classes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes).

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { /* initial state */ };
  }
}
```

is equivalent to

```js
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { /* initial state */ };
  },
});
```

**Note** that *in the constructor,* you should always assign to `this.state` directly, and that's the only place where this is allowed; You should use `this.setState(...)` everywhere else.

Comment: You do not need to add `props` as an argument to constructor unless you're using it. Similarly `super()` would be fine here

Comment: @inostia the React documentation recommends to always pass `props` to `super()` (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class). But I don't know the reason for that recommendation. You're right, passing `props` to `super()` is not actually necessary since `this.props` is still accessible in `render()` and other methods either way. Perhaps the recommendation is for compatibility with potential future features.

Comment: This is the most relevant section of the React doc: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html#setting-the-initial-state

Comment: @AlexandreKirszenberg If you were calling a function from your constructor would you still modify `this.state` in that function, or rather use `setState()` instead? (Supposing the function is only ever called from the constructor.)

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston You would need to modify `this.state` directly. I'd recommend making functions that take in `(state, props)` and return a new state, so that you can either do `this.state = myFn(null, props)` in the constructor or `this.setState(myFn)` anywhere else.

Comment: In the second example (`createClass`) you can use `this.getInitialState()` later in your code whereas in the first example you cannot revert the state.

Answer (score 180):

The difference between `constructor` and `getInitialState` is the difference between **ES6** and **ES5** itself.
`getInitialState` is used with `React.createClass`  and
`constructor` is used with `React.Component`.

Hence the question boils down to advantages/disadvantages of using **ES6** or **ES5**.

Let's look at the difference in code

**ES5**

```
var TodoApp = React.createClass({ 
  propTypes: {
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },
  getInitialState () { 
    return {
      items: []
    }; 
  }
});
```

**ES6**

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }
};
```

There is an interesting [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/35ed7s/es6_or_es5_in_reactjs/) regarding this.

React community is moving closer to **ES6**. Also it is considered as the best practice.

There are some differences between `React.createClass` and `React.Component`. For instance, how `this` is handled in these cases. Read more about such differences [in this blogpost](https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/) and facebook's [content on autobinding](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding)

`constructor` can also be used to handle such situations. To bind methods to a component instance, it can be pre-bonded in the `constructor`. [This](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/refactoring-react-components-to-es6-classes) is a good material to do such cool stuff.

Some more good material on best practices
[Best Practices for Component State in React.js](http://brewhouse.io/blog/2015/03/24/best-practices-for-component-state-in-reactjs.html)
[Converting React project from ES5 to ES6](http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2015/09/29/converting-es5-react-to-es6)

**Update: April 9, 2019,**:

With the new changes in Javascript class API, you don't need a constructor.

You could do

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {

    this.state = {items: []}
};
```

This will still get transpiled to constructor format, but you won't have to worry about it. you can use this format that is more readable.

[image: react hooks image] **With React Hooks**

From React version 16.8, there's a new API Called hooks.

Now, you don't even need a class component to have a state. It can even be done in a functional component.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function TodoApp () {
  const items = useState([]);
```

Note that the initial state is passed as an argument to `useState`; `useState([])`

Read more about react hooks [from the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Comment: The difference radicates on the ES version you are using

Comment: Isn't there also a 3rd way of constructing object, as a functional 'State Hook' ?  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html   I am new to react-native, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Hi @djangofan, I wanted to update this for some time now. Thank you for pushing me in that direction. I've added the new short hand with class fields and `useState` with React hooks.

Comment: Can you explain what is `super()` and why we pass props to them as an argument? @sudobangbang

Answer (score 36):

OK, the big difference is start from where they are coming from, so `constructor` is the constructor of your class in JavaScript, on the other side, `getInitialState` is part of the `lifecycle` of `React`.

`constructor` is where your class get initialised...

> **Constructor**
>
> The constructor method is a special method for creating and
>   initializing an object created with a class. There can only be one
>   special method with the name "constructor" in a class. A SyntaxError
>   will be thrown if the class contains more than one occurrence of a
>   constructor method.
>
> A constructor can use the super keyword to call the constructor of a
>   parent class.

In the React v16 document, they didn't mentioned any preference, but you need to `getInitialState` if you using `createReactClass()`...

> **Setting the Initial State**
>
> In ES6 classes, you can define the initial state by assigning
>   this.state in the constructor:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
  }
  // ...
}
```

> With createReactClass(), you have to provide a separate
>   getInitialState method that returns the initial state:

```
var Counter = createReactClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {count: this.props.initialCount};
  },
  // ...
});
```

Visit [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#setting-the-initial-state) for more information.

Also created the image below to show few lifecycles of React Compoenents:

[image: React lifecycle]

Comment: I would suggest adding `componentWillReceiveProps` to the diagram, since the OP was about state in components.

Comment: Can you explain what is `super()` and why we pass props to them as an argument? @Alireza

Answer (score 11):

If you are writing React-Native class with ES6, following format will be followed. It includes life cycle methods of RN for the class making network calls.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
     AppRegistry, StyleSheet, View, Text, Image
     ToastAndroid
} from 'react-native';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';

export default class RNClass extends Component{
     constructor(props){
          super(props);

          this.state= {
               uri: this.props.uri,
               loading:false
          }
     }

     renderLoadingView(){
          return(
               <View style={{justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',flex:1}}>
                    <Progress.Circle size={30} indeterminate={true} />
                    <Text>
                        Loading Data...
                    </Text>
               </View>
          );
     }

     renderLoadedView(){
          return(
               <View>

               </View>
          );
     }

     fetchData(){
          fetch(this.state.uri)
               .then((response) => response.json())
               .then((result)=>{

               })
               .done();

               this.setState({
                         loading:true
               });
               this.renderLoadedView();
     }

     componentDidMount(){
          this.fetchData();
     }

     render(){
          if(!this.state.loading){
               return(
                    this.renderLoadingView()
               );
          }

          else{

               return(
                    this.renderLoadedView()
               );
          }
     }
}

var style = StyleSheet.create({

});
```

Answer (score 2):

These days we don't have to call the constructor inside the component - we can directly call `state={something:""}`, otherwise previously first we have do declare constructor with `super()` to inherit every thing from `React.Component` class
then inside constructor we initialize our state.

If using `React.createClass` then define initialize state with the `getInitialState` method.

Answer (score 0):

The big difference is start from where they are coming from, so constructor is the constructor of your class in JavaScript, on the other side, getInitialState is part of the lifecycle of React . The constructor method is a special method for creating and initializing an object created with a class.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for answer then this link will be helpful
[Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-using-constructor-vs-getinitialstate-in-react/)

> The constructor and getInitialState both in React are used to
> initialise state, but they can't be used interchangeably.
>
> We use getInitialState with React.createClass and constructor is used
> with React.Component.

The constructor is the ideal place to set up your component's initial state. Instead of using setState() in other methods, you will need to assign the initial state directly.

```
class Hello extends React.Component { 
   constructor(props) { 
   super(props); 
   this.setState({ 
  title: 'This is the first test' 
   }); 
}   
  render() { 
    return <div>{this.state.title} </div> 
  } 
}   
ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

> The main fundamental difference between ES5 and ES6 is in the new
> class keyword. ES5 didn't provide the convenience of defining the
> React component as classes however ES did provide the convenience to
> define react component as class.
>
> and more simple is that getInitialState is the ES5 friendly method to
> define the initial state of a React component. We use getInitialState
> with React.createClass and constructor is used with React.Component

Example:

```
class Goodmorning extends React.Component { 
  render() { 
    return <span>Good Morning</span>; 
  } 
}
It would rely on helper module called create-react-class: 
var createGoodmorningReactClass = require('create-react-class'); 
var Goodmorning = createReactClass({ 
  render: function() { 
    return <span>Good Morning</span>; 
  } 
}); 
The object passed into create-react-class that is defined in initial stage by calling the getInitialState attribute: 
 var Goodmorning = createReactClass({ 
  getInitialState: function() { 
    return {name: this.props.name}; 
  }, 
  render: function() { 
    return <span>Good {this.state.name}</span>; 
  } 
}); 
In ES6 implementation: 
class Goodmorning extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props); 
    this.state = { 
      name: props.name 
    } 
  } 
  render() { 
    return <span>Good {this.state.name}</span>; 
  } 
}
```

and also read this article if someone is still looking for an answer.
[Link](https://www.knowledgehut.com/blog/web-development/understanding-constructors-with-react-components)

Answer (score -1):

In constructor we should always initialize the state.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).