# How to apply classList.toggle("active") in reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How to apply `classList.toggle("active")` in reactjs.
i create a two buttons and give `onclick` function `togglePopup` and define it at top. but i'm confused how to apply `document.getElementById('popup-1').classList.toggle("active")`in react. i apply this method in javaScript and i don't know how it is work in react?

***Popup.jsx***

```
const Filter = () => {
    const togglePopup = () => {
    document.getElementById('popup-1').classList.toggle("active")
    }
    return (
        <>
<button className='p-3 border bg-blue-400'>click</button>
            <div className="popup" id="popup-1">
                <div className="overlay"></div>
                <div className="content">
                    <div className="close-btn" onClick={togglePopup}>&times;</div>
                    <h1 className='text-2xl font-bold'>title</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non debitis officia neque nostrum, perspiciatis sed quaerat veritatis numquam, explicabo dolorum aliquam illo dolor at nemo maxime consequatur facilis magni laudantium! Ipsa eveniet quam, illum quos laudantium a placeat temporibus dolores libero pariatur quibusdam atque impedit magnam nam ipsum, rerum sapiente?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

***Popup.css***

```
.popup .overlay{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}
.popup .content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    background: #fff;
    width: 450px;
    height: fit-content;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup .close-btn{
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.popup:active .overlay{
    display: block;
}
.popup:active .content{
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);

}
```

Comment: Normally, you should not manipulate the DOM manually with React. You can define a [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and toggle the state on click. Then if the state is `true`, include desired classname in the attr.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toggle Class in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36403101/toggle-class-in-react)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not be querying or manipulating the DOM from React. If you want to toggle a class have your button update your component’s state and then render the markup according to that state.

```
function MyComponent () {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={active ? 'active' : ''}>
      <button onClick={() => setActive(!active)}>Toggle</button>
    </div>
  )

}
```