# ReactJs Select add default value

Tags: javascript, html, select, reactjs

I want to store select default value if user not touch it in ReactJs. How is that possible?

```
<select onChange={this.valSelected.bind(this)}>
    {currencies.map(function(name, index){
        return <option value={name}>{name}</option>;
    })}
</select>
```

and

```
valSelected(event){
    this.setState({
        valSelected: event.target.value
    });
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just add a value property to the select element, set by your state.

```
<select value={this.state.valSelected} onChange={this.valSelected.bind(this)}>
    {currencies.map(function(name, index){
        return <option value={name}>{name}</option>;
    })}
</select>
```

This is described here in the react docs: [Doc Link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag)

Then set a default state for the component, either in the constructor or with getInitialState: [What is the difference between using constructor vs getInitialState in React / React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668326/what-is-the-difference-between-using-constructor-vs-getinitialstate-in-react-r)

Answer (score 2):

Use `defaultValue` to select the default value.

```
    const statusOptions = [
        { value: 1, label: 'Publish' },
        { value: 0, label: 'Unpublish' }
    ];
    const [statusValue, setStatusValue] = useState('');
    const handleStatusChange = e => {
        setStatusValue(e.value);
    }

return(
<>
<Select options={statusOptions} defaultValue={[{ value: published, label: published == 1 ? 'Publish' : 'Unpublish' }]} onChange={handleStatusChange} value={statusOptions.find(obj => obj.value === statusValue)} required />
</>
)
```