# How to fix defaultValue of select when using ".map" to get options?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a `<select>` tag. The options for this tag are contained in an array. The values of this array are the fields I want to show to the user, and the index is the value I want to provide to my "onChange" function. So far, so good.
However, when I open the popup containing the `<select>`, the default value is not the value I set.

I have tried setting `defaultValue`, `value` and I of course checked the value I wanted as default.

Here is a sample of what I mean:

```
options = ["string1", "string2", "string3", ...];
valueIWant = options[indexGivenToFunction];

(...)

<select name="content" defaultValue={valueIWant} onChange={this.changeContent}>
    { options.map((opt, index) => {
        return (
            <option value={ index } key={ opt }>{ opt }</option>
        );
    })}
</select>
```

I would like the defaultValue when opening my popup to be the one I set here.
However, it seems to be set to the first value of my array.

A (very) wild guess I'm making is that because select doesn't allow any other fields than the ones it provides, and because when I set the defaultValue `options.map` isn't resolved yet, it ignores the value I give it, and instead takes the first option as entry for this field (as I said, just a guess). Am I right? And is there a way to bypass this behaviour to be able to set a defaultValue anyway?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried `value` instead of `defaultValue`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJs Select add default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943554/reactjs-select-add-default-value)

Comment: @Ragnar, Is not the value of an option an index of the array, while defaultValue as an item of that array?

Comment: Is that your exact code?  You have a typo, you set `valueIWant` to `option` not `options` with an "s".

Comment: I guess either defaultValue should be an index too, or option's value should be an `opt`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Yes I did. Didn't work.

Comment: @Yozi Yes it is, I'm working with the index to do my changes, but for the user it wouldn't be readable. I didn't even think about giving an index to default value,
I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: @sanjsanj Not my code, but typo fixed, thanks!

Comment: @Yozi It worked, I was just tired I guess. However, I think using different values as display and *actual* value and trying to set a defaultValue as I did might throw off a few beginners such as me. Should I create an answer in case someone has the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use  the * tagged line before map .

Your default value*
    { options.map((opt, index) => {
        return (
            { opt }

Comment: would you edit your answer with a code snippet (not just text)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're question is how to dynamically set default value for dropdown, and if this is your doubt then,
Pseudocode:

```
let Quantity_array=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
//too render the option




    <select name={Quantity} value={Desired_number} id="Qty" >
{
    Quantity_array.map((number,index)=>{
        return(
        <option key={index} value={index}>{index}</option>

        )
    })
}
        </select>
```

**Desired_number:-default value;**
**note :to set default you can add selected attribute in option;
and if the default value is dynamic then in selected={write condition for  that}**
Or
in select tag use value attribute and set Desired_number to make it default